# make the wrapping div at least the same height as the bigger div

Tags: css

I've got one wrapping div and two divs with different height inside them. How can I make sure that the wrapping div is always at least the height of the bigger div inside it because for some reason I see that when in the `.leftMenu` div there is a lot of info (both divs are dynamically filled with info) - the wrapping div stays as the height of `.centerBody`!  (I've put on purpose the styles of divs inline so its quicker)

My code:

```
<div id="importPartUpdate">               
 <div class="leftMenu" style="position: relative;margin-top: 10px;width: 15%;clear: both;display: inline-lock;float: left;" />        
 <div class="centerBody" style="margin-top: 10px;margin-left: 0px; display: inline-block; position: reative;width: 83%;padding: 5px;"/>                      
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear your div floats using `clear:both` CSS property.

```
 <div id="importPartUpdate">               
  <div class="leftMenu" style="position: relative;margin-top: 10px;width: 15%;clear: both;display: inline-lock;float: left;" />        
  <div class="centerBody" style="margin-top: 10px;margin-left: 0px; display: inline-block; position: reative;width: 83%;padding: 5px;"/>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>                      
</div>
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/G6jHD/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:flex;`. Check this link: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Here's the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NhKb6/2/